# Numerically Calculating the solution of very complex equations

Tags: numerical-methods

I wanted to confirm a question of my own, and I figured out if there is a solution of the following equations such that every variable is real and $x,y\ge 0$, my question could be partially verified.

[image]

[image]

However, after two hours of running Mathematica, I thought that this would not give me the solution, and aborted it. Is there a good way to calculate a numerical solution of an equation as complex as this? I tried using other kinds of equations which the solution is known, but it didn't work either.

I really want to calculate a solution, or prove that this has a solution. Any ideas?

**Edit.** I add a Mathematica code for solving the equations:

```
t0813[x_, y_, z_, a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_] := 
a x^3 + b y^3 + c z^3 + d x^2 y + e x y^2 + f y ^2 z + g y z^2 + 
h z^2 x + i z x^2 + j x y z 

NSolve[{t0813[1, 1, 1, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j] == 0, 
  t0813[1, x, y, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j] == 0, 
  t0813[1, y, x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j] == 0, 
  t0813[x, 1, y, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j] == 0, 
  t0813[y, 1, x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j] == 0, 
  t0813[x, y, 1, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j] == 0, 
  t0813[y, x, 1, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j] == 0, 
  a^2 + b^2 + c^2 == 1, 
  2 a d + 2 b e + 2 b f + 2 c g + 2 c h + 2 a i == 0.01 - 700/102, 
  2 b d + d^2 + 2 a e + e^2 + 2 c f + f^2 + 2 b g + g^2 + 2 a h + 
  h^2 + 2 c i + i^2 == 1124/102, 
  2 e f + 2 g h + 2 d i + 2 a j + 2 b j + 2 c j == 738/102, 
  2 a b + 2 a c + 2 b c + 2 d e + 2 f g + 2 h i == -564/102}, {a, b, 
  c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, x, y}]
```

Comment: please post the original problem i can try it with Maple

Comment: The equations are in the question. I have to find a solution of this.

Comment: The original question of mine is fairly hard to do with a computer. It's whether a specific polynomial of degree 6 which is not exactly defined, can be expressed a sum of squares of polynomials. The definition of this specific polynomial is defined by its coefficients. Five of its coefficients is given, and the polynomial itself is defined as minimizing the sixth coefficient while the sum of its coefficient is 0, and it has to be psd.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner If you want to Ctrl+C,V it, I will edit the question.

Comment: do you have numerical values for the variables?

Comment: No, I have to find them

Comment: Hello, Houtarou-san! Please use the triple-space when you type a code source.

Comment: @Houtarou Asking on SE communities is sometimes difficult due to unawareness of writing style or syntax of questions on SE, so we can edit questions written by others!

Comment: Can you please double-check the numbers? It seems that the system does not have a solution

Comment: Is there a typo and `1124/702` should really be `1124/102`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system has the following form
$$
\begin{cases}
\mathbf F_7(x,y,\mathbf p) = 0\\
\mathbf G_5(\mathbf p) = 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
with $\mathbf p = (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j), \mathbf r = (x, y, z)$. $\mathbf F_7$ are seven equations linear in $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf G_5$ are nonlinear equations in $\mathbf p$.
We have
$$
T(\mathbf r,\mathbf p) = ax^3 + by^3 + cz^3 + dx^2 y + e xy^2 + f y^2 z + g y z^2 + h z^2 x + i z x^2 + j x y z,
$$
thus $$
\mathbf F_7(x,y, \mathbf p) = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & x^3 & y^3 & x & x^2 & x^2 y & x y^2 & y^2 & y & x y \\
 1 & y^3 & x^3 & y & y^2 & x y^2 & x^2 y & x^2 & x & x y \\
 x^3 & 1 & y^3 & x^2 & x & y & y^2 & x y^2 & x^2 y & x y \\
 y^3 & 1 & x^3 & y^2 & y & x & x^2 & x^2 y & x y^2 & x y \\
 x^3 & y^3 & 1 & x^2 y & x y^2 & y^2 & y & x & x^2 & x y \\
 y^3 & x^3 & 1 & x y^2 & x^2 y & x^2 & x & y & y^2 & x y 
\end{pmatrix}}_{\mathbf A}\mathbf{p}.
$$
Let's consider case when $0 < x < y, x \neq 1, y \neq 1$. Let $\mathbf B$ be the following submatrix of $\mathbf A$:
$$
\mathbf B = \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 x & x^2 & x^2 y & x y^2 & y^2 & y & x y \\
 y & y^2 & x y^2 & x^2 y & x^2 & x & x y \\
 x^2 & x & y & y^2 & x y^2 & x^2 y & x y \\
 y^2 & y & x & x^2 & x^2 y & x y^2 & x y \\
 x^2 y & x y^2 & y^2 & y & x & x^2 & x y \\
 x y^2 & x^2 y & x^2 & x & y & y^2 & x y
\end{pmatrix}\\
\operatorname{det} \mathbf B = 
(x-1)^3 (y-1)^3 (y-x)^3 (x+y+1)^2 (x y+x+y)^2 \left((x+1) y^2+(x-6) x y+x (x+1)+y\right) \neq 0.
$$
Now we can express $d,e,f,g,h,i,j$ in terms of $x,y,a,b,c$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
d\\e\\f\\g\\h\\i\\j
\end{pmatrix}
= \frac{1}{\operatorname{det}(\mathbf B)}\mathbf{M}\begin{pmatrix}
a\\b\\c
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\mathbf{M} \equiv -\operatorname{det}(\mathbf B)\mathbf{B}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1\\
 1 & x^3 & y^3 \\
 1 & y^3 & x^3 \\
 x^3 & 1 & y^3 \\
 y^3 & 1 & x^3 \\
 x^3 & y^3 & 1 \\
 y^3 & x^3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
or in terms of $(\xi, \eta, \zeta) = \frac{(a,b,c)}{\operatorname{det}(\mathbf B)}$
$$
\mathbf p
= \mathbf {Rw}
\qquad
\mathbf R(x,y) \equiv \begin{pmatrix}
\operatorname{det}(\mathbf B) \mathbf I_3\\
\mathbf{M}
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
\mathbf{w} \equiv
\begin{pmatrix}
\xi\\ \eta\\ \zeta
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now we've completely eliminated equations $\mathbf F_7$ and
ended up with five equations in five unknowns $x,y,\xi,\eta,\zeta$.
Since every equation in $\mathbf G_5(\mathbf p) = 0$ can be written as
$$
\mathbf p^\top \mathbf Q_i \mathbf p = \alpha_i, \quad \mathbf Q_i^\top = \mathbf Q_i \quad i = 1,2,3,4,5.
$$
we can rewrite them in terms of $\mathbf w$:
$$
\mathbf w^\top \underbrace{\mathbf R^\top \mathbf Q_i
\mathbf R}_{\mathbf S_i} \mathbf w = \alpha_i
$$
Every $\mathbf S_i$ matrix has form
$$
\mathbf S_i = \begin{pmatrix}
a_i & b_i & b_i\\
b_i & a_i & b_i\\
b_i & b_i & a_i
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I think this is due to it should stay the same when $\xi, \eta, \zeta$ are permuted, thus the equations reduce to
$$
a_i(x,y) (\xi^2 + \eta^2 + \zeta^2) + b_i(x,y) (2\xi \eta + 2\xi \zeta + 2\eta \zeta) = \alpha_i, \quad i = 1,2,3,4,5
$$
Introducing $\sigma = \xi^2 + \eta^2 + \zeta^2, \tau = 2\xi \eta + 2\xi \zeta + 2\eta \zeta$ we see that
$$
a_i(x,y) \sigma + b_i(x,y) \tau = \alpha_i, \quad i = 1,2,3,4,5.
$$
is a linear system with five equations in two unknowns $\sigma, \tau$, thus solvable only if
$$
\operatorname{rank}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1(x,y) & b_1(x,y)\\
\vdots&\vdots\\
a_5(x,y) & b_5(x,y)
\end{pmatrix}
=
\operatorname{rank}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1(x,y) & b_1(x,y) & \alpha_1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
a_5(x,y) & b_5(x,y) & \alpha_5
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since the left matrix seems to have rank $2$, we need to solve 
$$\left\{
\begin{gathered}
\begin{vmatrix}
a_1(x,y) & b_1(x,y) & \alpha_1\\
a_2(x,y) & b_2(x,y) & \alpha_2\\
a_3(x,y) & b_3(x,y) & \alpha_3
\end{vmatrix} = 0\\
\begin{vmatrix}
a_2(x,y) & b_2(x,y) & \alpha_2\\
a_3(x,y) & b_3(x,y) & \alpha_3\\
a_4(x,y) & b_4(x,y) & \alpha_4
\end{vmatrix} = 0\\
\begin{vmatrix}
a_3(x,y) & b_3(x,y) & \alpha_3\\
a_4(x,y) & b_4(x,y) & \alpha_4\\
a_5(x,y) & b_5(x,y) & \alpha_5
\end{vmatrix} = 0\end{gathered}\right.
$$
for $x,y$.

So either you're extremely lucky with $\alpha_i$ so the over-determined polynomial system has roots, in which case there's a solution $(\sigma,  \tau)$ and the problem is to find the intersection of a sphere and a hyperboloid
$$
\begin{cases}
\xi^2 + \eta^2 + \zeta^2 = \sigma\\
(\xi+\eta+\zeta)^2 - (\xi^2 + \eta^2 + \zeta^2) = 2\xi\eta + 2\xi\zeta + 2\eta\zeta = \tau
\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}
\xi^2 + \eta^2 + \zeta^2 = \sigma\\
\xi+\eta+\zeta = \sqrt{\tau + \sigma}
\end{cases}
$$
which itself may have no solutions, one solution or infinitely many solutions.

But For arbitrary $\alpha_i$ the system for $\sigma, \tau$ is inconsistent whatever $x,y$ you take.

Comment: Thank you. I doubt that this would have a solution.
Actually, this has a solution when 0.01-700/102 becomes -700/102. 0.01 was a random number, so I don't think that this would have a solution. I would try this with my computer.

Comment: However, I am quite confident that this would also be hard for a computer to calculate...

Comment: @Houtarou I tried removing $0.01$ with no changes. I can share my Mathematica notebook file if you need that. Can you please share your solution for $\alpha_2 = -\frac{700}{102}$?

Comment: @Houtarou And, please, check the $\alpha_3$ value, I believe it should be $\alpha_3 = \frac{1124}{102}$, not $\alpha_3 = \frac{1124}{702}$

Comment: Oh, that is correct. $\alpha_3 = \frac {1124} {102}$

Comment: For the solution without 0.01, $x=2, y=3$ and $\mathbf{p}=\frac {1} {\sqrt{102}} (1\ 1\ -10\ 3\ 3\ -8\ 17\ 17\ -8\ -16)$

Comment: I became much more confident that my original equation will have no solution. Thank you